# Find the values between the range of 100's and their count

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

In excel I can make the group the column and count but iam unable to do it in R.

For doing in R i am using cut function with some breaks.

```
cut(elapsed, breaks=seq(min(elapsed),max(elapsed)+100,50), include.lowest=T)
```

here i attached the png of the data and required output.
but above code not give my require output.

this is the my data

[image: input data]

and my required output:

```
 400       9
 500       4
 600       2
 700       5
 800       3
 900       3
```

Comment: After you `cut`, you need to aggregate in some manner. `table` makes the most sense here.

Comment: To make your example reproducible please share output of `dput(elapsed)` in question summary. And I agree with @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1, you need to use the `table` function after using `cut`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
data.frame(table(elapsed %/% 100))
```

For example:

```
elapsed <- c(400, 423, 423, 534, 534, 639, 602, 812, 703)
data.frame(table(elapsed %/% 100))
  Var1 Freq
1    4    3
2    5    2
3    6    2
4    7    1
5    8    1
```

For desired result in hundreds use this:

```
res <- data.frame(table(elapsed %/% 100))
res$Var1 <- as.numeric(res$Var1) * 100
```

Comment: @ PoGibas hi ,it's not satisfied my complete requirement but this give some idea.where i did mistake.I try in different way using the ggplot2 .I am not sure is it correct process or not.`ggplot_build(ggplot() + aes(elapsed) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 100) )$data[1][[1]][,c(2:3)].`the code works perfectly for my requirement.

Comment: And My data is dynamically change every time, based on that i should adjust the intervals**(100 to 10,000).**And count how many values are fall in the intervals. can you give any idea ,how can i change the intervals based on the dynamic data. Thankyou

Answer (score 2):

you can try:

```
require(magrittr)

elapsed <- runif(100, 400, 1000) %>% round

cut(elapsed, breaks = seq(400,1000,100), 
    labels = as.character(seq(400,900,100)), 
    include.lowest=TRUE) %>% table
```

gives you:

```
400 500 600 700 800 900 
 15  22  16   9  20  18
```

Comment: No `plyr` functions are used in this answer. You could load `magrittr` for the pipe, (or `dplyr`, I suppose, less directly). For newby questions I would recommend either not using the pipe at all or explaining what it is. (And explaining that it's not absolutely necessary.)